# ListView - weird problem, as it has been partially covered by something

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a very strange problem. 
I have a user control with listview inside. My user control is inside ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Grid.Row="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <app:MySuperUserControl Margin="5" />
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Now I have 3 user controls lying next to each other. First two work ok, but the weird problem is with the third one. Look at this gif:

[image]

This simple example shows this weird behaviour. ListView should change color to red in MouseEnter and should lost the color in MouseLeave.

As you can see the behaviour is not exactly as expected. ListView doesn't change its color as soon as I enter the mouse, but at some distance. The same is with column headers which you can also see in this example.

THe biggest problem is MouseDoubleClick. It also works at some distance, not in all listView. As if something has been covering this ListView, but I don't have any idea what could it be and how to check it.

Any ideas? Did someone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I got the answer.
On the main window near to the control the was another one invisible control that made the problem. This control has been positioned directly on screen center from top to bottom.